# Join two tables based on a foreign key which a substring of column?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have the two following tables

**Order**

```
ID|      DETAILS       | AMOUNT
-------------------------------
0 |#Battery#Client1234 | 90USD
```

**Client**

```
ID   |  NAME
--------------
1234 | JohnDoe
```

How can I join these two tables since the foreign key in the Order table is aggregated with some other information ?

Comment: The best option is to normalize your tables and data also will allow indexing.  Joining with `ON order.details LIKE CONCAT('%', client.ID ,'%').`  should work.but it will never use anny indexes if anny.

Comment: Note that ORDER is a reserved word in MySQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extract the client id from the order details using [MySQL SUBSTRING_INDEX() function](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-substring_index-function.php) and use it to do a join with the client table. Here is the query:

```
SELECT *
FROM `order` o
LEFT JOIN client c
ON c.id=SUBSTRING_INDEX(o.details,'#Client',-1);
```

**[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a8c9f6/4)**

Answer (score 3):

Break your column `DETAILS` into two `OrderDerails` and `CLientID` and join ClientID with second table.

Answer (score 1):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a8c9f6/1

```
SELECT o.*, c.*
FROM `order` o
LEFT JOIN client c
ON o.details LIKE CONCAT('%#Client',c.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Orders oo
JOIN Client cc
ON oo.details LIKE CONCAT('%', cc.id, '%');
```